# Use video as background of view controller iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, background

Does anyone know how I can use a background video as the login like how AirBNB had their log in screen before? I tried to use a gif, but felt like it didn't have great resolution.

Please let me know! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not tried it myself but it should at least send you to the right direction:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]
    NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your_video_file_name" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
    // or get your videoURL some another way
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    [moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view insertSubview:moviePlayer.view atIndex:0]; // to be sure it is a background
//  [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [moviePlayer play];
}
```